# C++ read string with spaces

Tags: c++, istream

I have file like this:

```
59 137 New York
137 362 Syracuse
216 131 New Jersey
...
..
.
```

and I would like to read it to a structure:
X - Y - name of a city

```
  char city[100];
  int x , y;
  f.open("map.txt");
  f >> x >> y >> city;
  while (!f.fail()) {
    f >> x >> y >> city;
  }
  f.close();
```

Problem is, that city reads only until next space, so from New York it reads only New.
How should I read whole rest of a line, in some easy and smart way ?

Comment: You should make city an `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of your file seems to imply that the name of the city ends at the *end of a line*, not a *space*.

You can read that form using [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

```
  char city[100];
  int x , y;
  f.open("map.txt");
  while ( f ) {
      f >> x >> y;         
      f.getline(city, 100); 
  }
  f.close();
```

Comment: thank you for response, shouldn't be the same change inside the while too ?

Comment: @Simon YES!  Thanks for catching that.  Note that I simplified the code as well.  An `istream` can be used alone in [a bool context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

Comment: Thank you, do i need also to change char city[100] to a string city; ?

Comment: @Simon while you don't *need* to, there are many protections that a `std::string` offer that an array won't.  In that case, you would want `std::getline( f, city );`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
  f.open("map.txt");
  string city;
  int x , y;
  f >> x >> y;
  getline(f,city);

  while (!f.fail()) {
  f >> x >> y;
  getline(f,city);
  }
  f.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getline(f, city) for city. So, you have f >> x >> y; getline(f, city);

Answer (score 1):

This code reads spaces and handles end of file correctly. None of the other answers do this I think

```
while ((f >> x >> y).getline(city, 100))
{
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for more information on how to correctly test for end of file.

Of course you should be doing things the easy way using `std::string` as others have said.